# Sensor Div Overlapping Ambiente Div

Tags: html, css, web

[The sensor section is overlapping the ambiente section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOJT.png)
[they are 5 boxes at the ambiente zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WDlw.png)
I would like to put this sensor section static starting at a aligned postion with UPS EATON section and from there be static until the end of the page

heres the code. the top fuction let me define the space starting from the top of the page, if i give more than 165px this sensores section i would move down but it stays satic so doesnt let ypu see the rest of the info.

heres the code of that specific part.

when the page is louded, the seosnres sections dont show there and appers aligned with de UPS section, and from there be static and if yo scroll up stops before overlapping the ambiente zone

```css
/* Estilos para el límite de desplazamiento */
.side-limits {
    position: fixed;
    top: 165px; 
    right: 20px; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 300px; 
}

/* Estilos para el cuadro estático */
.side-static {
    position: fixed;
    top: 165px; 
    right: 200px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #f00; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    /* margin-top: 80px; */
}


.side-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: left;
    flex-direction: column; 
    height: 100vh; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -250px;
    
    /* ESTE ES EL MAIN-CONTAINER 
    Estilos para el contenedor principal, si es necesario */
}

.side-tittle {
    margin: 0;
    /* Estilos para el título del cuadro, si es necesario */
}

.side-custom {
    background-color: #e0e0e0; /* Color de fondo más oscuro del contenedor */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Esquinas redondeadas */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Sombra para resaltar el contenedor */
    max-width: 1400px; /* Anchura máxima del contenedor */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Añadir un margen superior para separar del h2 */
    width: 300px;
    height: 495px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    /* ESTE ES EL CISTOM-CONTAINER
    Estilos para el contenedor personalizado, si es necesario */
}

.side-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;

    /* CONTAINER-ITEMS
    Estilos para los ítems dentro del contenedor, si es necesario */
}

.side-box {
    background-color: #d0d0d0; /* Color de fondo de los rectángulos internos */
    flex: 1;
    height: px;
    width: 290px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* Esquinas redondeadas */
    margin: 5px;
    /* 
    INNER-BOX
    Estilos para el cuadro dentro del contenedor, si es necesario */
}
```

```html
<div class="side-limits" id="side-limits">
        <div class="side-static">
            <div class="side-container">
                <h2>Sensores</h2>
                <div class="side-custom">
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Agua Piso</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Temperatura</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Humo</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Seguridad</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)?